# Is this php code a bad idea?

Tags: php, javascript, netbeans

I have written the following while loop in a php file.  The file does exactly what I want it to do.  However, my code editing program (Netbeans IDE 7.0.1) keeps indicating the following error: "missing ) after argument list". The error is attached to the line inside the javascript tags.  Is there a problem in how I'm creating the var Topcaption?  The code seems to work fine in IE, FF and Chrome.  Thanks for any advice you can offer!

```php
    if ($totalRows_Top_Slides != 0) {
    mysql_data_seek($Top_Slides,0);
    $i = 1;
    $j = 100;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($Top_Slides)) {             
        ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var Topcaption<?php echo $i;?>  = "<?php echo $row['caption'];?>";
            </script>
        <?php
        $Top_images .= "<img id=\"Topimage" . $i . "\" class=\"slide_out\" style=\"z-index: " . $j . "\" src=\"" . $row['file_folder'] . $row['file'] . "\" width=\"280\" height=\"170\" alt=\"\" />";
        $i = $i + 1;
        $j = $j - 1;
    }
```

Comment: Are you escaping the `$row['caption']` to ensure it doesn't have any double quotes in it and that it doesn't end in a backslash?

Comment: Yes, it goes into the database that way. Thanks

Comment: php code looks ok, you cat try using heredoc so netbeans will not try to interpret it as javascript with errors. On the other hand, your javascript code is very bad idea...

Comment: I would say yes, it may be me but i find it unclear as to what you are trying to achieve, building javascript with php sounds like it will lead to a headache, you seem to be creating a lot of global js var's when you can use an array, pretty sure you camelCase var's in php as you would in js, you should avoid setting style within you markup, as much as possible remove anything that isn't html away from html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Tom, they make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've pasted your sample code into my version of NetBeans on Ubuntu and it simply appears to be a bug in *NetBeans 7.0.1*. To fix, [upgrade to **Netbeans 7.1**](http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html).

As a side-note, for sanity's sake, I recommend changing your code to:

```
<?php
mysql_data_seek($Top_Slides,0);
$i = 1;
$j = 100;
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($Top_Slides)) {             
 echo 'var Topcaption'.$i.' = "'.$row['caption'].'";';
 $Top_images .= "<img id=\"Topimage" . $i . "\" class=\"slide_out\" style=\"z-index: " . $j . "\" src=\"" . $row['file_folder'] . $row['file'] . "\" width=\"280\" height=\"170\" alt=\"\" />";
 $i = $i + 1;
 $j = $j - 1;
}
echo '</script>';
?>
```

That way, you will only have 1 script tag, rather than 100.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: bfrohs, nice catch that script generation

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry about it,

Netbeans just doesn't know how to interpret that mix of code. It happens to me in Aptana to.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine to me.  It's possible that it's seeing something it doesn't like with the Topcaption variable you are declaring because it is also reading the php symbols which would be invalid for a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans can't handle JavaScript in PHP files, even though it handles HTML in PHP files just fine. You can safely ignore the error. If you want to get rid of the error, put the javascript in a .js and link to it instead from the  HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with the code specifically, but all those mixed tags are confusing the syntax checkers. I don't like to mix PHP and static output like that for reasons like this, and I would rewrite it to this:

```
if ($totalRows_Top_Slides != 0) {
  mysql_data_seek($Top_Slides,0);
  echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n";
  for ($i = 1, $j = 100; $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Top_Slides); $i++, $j--) {             
    echo "var Topcaption$i = \"{$row['caption']}\";\n";
    $Top_images .= "<img id=\"Topimage" . $i . "\" class=\"slide_out\" style=\"z-index: " . $j . "\" src=\"" . $row['file_folder'] . $row['file'] . "\" width=\"280\" height=\"170\" alt=\"\" />";
  }
  echo '</script>';
}
```

As you can see, the StackOverflow syntax parser also likes this version a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

**ATTENTION!**

If $row['caption'] is based on user-input your code's got a XSS vulnerability.

Also notice that htmlspecialchars will not work inside SCRIPT-tags (they might work, but won't do any good, since the purpose of the htmlspecialchars (and alike functions) is to prevent the attacker from injecting html tags (by converting <, >, &, etc..). However, inside SCRIPT-tags the attacker don't need to inject html tags in order to execute a XSS attack.

Take this in consideration.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Yawning.  In this situation there is no user-input.